# How to use clang-format package?

Tags: package, clang

I installed `clang-format` package from the MELPA repository.

I added it to the `load-path` in my init file.

Whenever I try to use it it says:

`Searching for program: No such file or directory, clang-format`

I would assume this is because I don't have some kind of style file. Is this correct?

If so, how would I create such a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`load_path`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath) is used for emacs lisp libraries, what you're looking for is [`exec-path`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath):

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/path/to/clang-format")))
```

Or you can customize `clang-format-executable`

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have clang-format installed on my machine. I thought it was an emacs-only package. Your answer gave me the hint. `sudo apt install clang-format`

Comment: So to choose a particular version of `clang-format:     (setq clang-format-executable "/usr/bin/clang-format-5.0")`

Comment: That's right. You can try it yourself.